How does Inbox worker mechanism work in the MassTransit
I don't quite undestand how inbox table worker works in MassTransit. My understanding is, if i have a simple consumer that only saves data into database(here message received is came from the inbox table worker, not from the broker directly)
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SendEmailWithOrderDetails> context)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Sending email to {Email} with order details", context.Message.Email);
    
    _dbContext.Emails.Add(new OrderSentEmail()
    {
        EmailAdress = context.Message.Email,
        Subject = "Order details",
        Body = context.Message.OrderDetails
    });
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    _logger.LogInformation("Email sent to {Email}", context.Message.Email);
}

Saving data into database, marking message as compeleted(what's the difference between consumed and delivered states?) and potential message publishing(saving entity into outbox table) all should be in a single transaction since we're using shared dbcontext and don't want any inconsistency.
Indeed, when in the middle of the Consume method i'm checking current transaction number there is one! But if i put a breakpoint right on the SaveChangesAsync() line and go forward, after this line data is saved into Emails table, but message in the InboxState table isn't marked neither as consumed, nor as delivered. Can't it create inconsistency since Emails table and message update in different transactions? Like what if right after saving changes database dies and we can't mark the message as completed. It basically means i should implement a "processed messages" table myself in order to achieve idempotency, and it means inbox table doesn't do much. It mitigates the problem, but doesn't solve it.
Also, when i'm consuming a message(i can guarantee it's only been published once into the consumer's queue) using this worker, InboxState table's ReceiveCount somehow manages to go up to 3. I'm testing it in localhost, and there's no way it was delivered 3 times from the broker to the consumer.

you can see the logs yourself by using docker-compose up on this repo https://github.com/usersuseruuseruser/MtSample . just use the order-send-with-email endpoint and see the consumer's logs

The inbox works, delivery count is how many times the message is run through the loop, which it does internally until all outbox messages have been delivered. The transaction is committed by the inbox, you calling SaveChanges in the consumer isn't the final call to the database.

@ChrisPatterson So my calls to db in the consumer and inbox/outbox message processing database calls are all in one transaction that is managed by transactional outbox? Then I don't understand why can i select data inserted right after SaveChangesAsync() but before method's end since it's uncommited change and Postgres default isolation level for select is read-commited

Then you have something either configured incorrectly or are using the wrong DbContext. Just a reminder, SO is not a support venue for MassTransit. If you have specific questions, you can reach out to support.
